Проблема с загрузкой файлов на сервер PHP/Yii2
Возникла проблема при загрузке файлов на сервер. На локали все работает без проблем, но при переносе на боевой сервер - попытка загрузить любой файл, больше ~18мб заканчивается 500 Internal Server Error, при этом POST-запрос судя по логам - даже не доехал до обработчика. Менял значения в php.ini, nginx.conf, httpd.conf, .htaccess - ничего не помогло. Код прикладываю ниже, буду благодарен за любую помощь
Контроллер, экшн с загрузкой файла
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->workDataFile = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'workDataFile');
        if ($model->workDataFile !== null) {
            $model->uploadWorkDataFile();
        }
        $model->save();
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }
}

uploadWorkData
public function uploadWorkData()
{
    $path = '@app/upload/files/training-group/work-data/';
    $date = $this->local_date;
    $new_date = '';
    $filename = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($date); ++$i) {
        if ($date[$i] != '-') {
            $new_date = $new_date.$date[$i];
        }
    }

    $filename = 'Вх.'.$new_date.'_'.$this->local_number.'_'.$this->company->short_name.'_'.$this->document_theme;
    $res = mb_ereg_replace('[ ]{1,}', '_', $filename);
    $res = mb_ereg_replace('[^а-яА-Я0-9._]{1}', '', $res);
    $res = FileWizard::CutFilename($res);
    $this->workData = $res.'.'.$this->workDataFile->extension;

    $this->workDataFile->saveAs($path.$res.'.'.$this->workDataFile->extension);
}


"судя по логам - даже не доехал до обработчика"  --- почему такой вывод? Типа никаких ошибок нет вообще?

500 - ошибка на сервере. Тут может быть например другая версия PHP.  Можно попробовать временно включить отображение ошибок)))) А можно подебажить удалённо.. Логи смотреть надо как от yii так и апачевские

@АлексейШиманский да, вообще никаких ошибок, но есть 500 ошибка по итогу, из-за чего возникает - непонятно...

а какие именно логи смотрел?  и какой error_reporting стоит в настройках?

@АлексейШиманский E_ALL, но там всего пара warning-ов, которые никак не сказываются на работе системы. Ошибок, связанных конкретно с эндпоинтом загрузки вообще нет, вероятно, до него не добрался

а вы включили "debug режим"? defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true); defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev'); /web/index.php

@YaMus конечно, все логи смотрел, но связанных именно с этим экшном - никаких не нашел. Как будто бы сам обработчик не вызывается, а ломается запрос на этапе формирования и до его отправки. При этом проблема возникла в момент когда мы перенесли систему с хостинга на выделенный сервер reg.ru

@ГлебКалашник а выделенный сервер у вас случаем не на windows?) Я думаю нужно целиком посмотреть что у вас там происходит.

@YaMus нет, упаси боже, на CentOS 7)

Проверьте настройки php на сервере: post_max_size и upload_max_filesize.
